# Google Form Response not working from the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-sheets, google-forms

I'm using a Google Forms value to integrate with my website where I want to submit the form and store data in google sheet as form responses. I'm using AJAX to redirect to another page instead of Google Form submit page. But whenever I'm trying to submit, it's redirecting to my page accurately but data is not saved in Google Sheet.

Here is my code:

```
<strong>Full Name</strong>
<input type="text" name="Fullname" class="form-control" id="Fullname" />
<strong>Email Address</strong>
<input type="text" name="Email" class="form-control" id="Email" />
<strong>Subject</strong>
<input type="text" name="Subject" class="form-control" id="Subject" />
<strong>Details</strong>
<textarea name="Details" rows="8" cols="0" class="form-control" id="Details"></textarea><br />
<button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="postContactToGoogle()">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function postContactToGoogle() {
        var email = $('#Email').val();
        var fullname = $('#FullName').val();
        var subject = $('#Subject').val();
        var details = $('#Details').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/abcdefgh1234567xyz/formResponse",
            data: {
                "entry_805356472": fullname,
                "entry_1998295708": email, "entry_785075795":
                subject, "entry_934055676": details
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            statusCode: {
                0: function () {
                    window.location.replace("Success.html");
                },
                200: function () {
                    window.location.replace("Success.html");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

How can I save the data in Google Sheet? Am I missing something in my code?

Comment: Can you add a `success` and an `error` method in your ajax call and do not redirect it, just print the response that comes from the ajax call using `console.log(data)`.

Comment: I'm noob to `ajax`. Can you provide a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly copy the form from google `view form` page like shown in the demo, and then do the following changes in the AJAX call as shown below.
And now once you submit data it is visible in google forms, view responses.

```js
$(function(){
    $('input:submit').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/18icZ41Cx3-n1iW7yTOZdiDx9a6mySWHOy9ryd1l59tM/formResponse",
            data:$('form').serialize(),
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(data){
              //window.location.replace("youraddress");
              //console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
              //console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="ss-form"><form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/18icZ41Cx3-n1iW7yTOZdiDx9a6mySWHOy9ryd1l59tM/formResponse" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="_self" onsubmit=""><ol role="list" class="ss-question-list" style="padding-left: 0">
<div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
<div dir="auto" class="ss-item  ss-text"><div class="ss-form-entry">
<label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_1635584241"><div class="ss-q-title">What's your name
</div>
<div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="auto"></div></label>
<input type="text" name="entry.1635584241" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1635584241" dir="auto" aria-label="What's your name  " title="">
<div class="error-message" id="1979924055_errorMessage"></div>
<div class="required-message">This is a required question</div>
</div></div></div>
<input type="hidden" name="draftResponse" value="[,,&quot;182895015706156721&quot;]
">
<input type="hidden" name="pageHistory" value="0">

<input type="hidden" name="fvv" value="0">


<input type="hidden" name="fbzx" value="182895015706156721">

<div class="ss-item ss-navigate"><table id="navigation-table"><tbody><tr><td class="ss-form-entry goog-inline-block" id="navigation-buttons" dir="ltr">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="ss-submit" class="jfk-button jfk-button-action ">
</td>
</tr></tbody></table></div></ol></form></div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I get `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error in my browser console!

Comment: Data is saving in the sheet but I get `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error in my browser console! Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Same here I'm not getting any error in FF, the ajax call returns html, I don't think they have enabled forms to be used like this, as it keeps saying that CORS is not enabled on the requested resource which is google. I am still looking for a way to fix this. Are you making this AJAX call from your local page or from some website?

Comment: What is the backend which you use, have you enabled CORS in your application?

Comment: I don't know and I'm not sure how to do that in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your form on Google and click on 'View Live Form', and then view source on the form, you'll see that the fields you want to upload have a`name` in the form `entry.12345678`; the `id` is in the form `entry_12345678`.  You need to use the `name` value.  Try this:

```
<script>
    function postContactToGoogle() {
        var email = $('#Email').val();
        var fullname = $('#FullName').val();
        var subject = $('#Subject').val();
        var details = $('#Details').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/abcdefgh1234567xyz/formResponse",
            data: {
                "entry.805356472": fullname,
                "entry.1998295708": email, 
                "entry.785075795":  subject, 
                "entry.934055676": details
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            statusCode: {
                0: function () {
                    window.location.replace("Success.html");
                },
                200: function () {
                    window.location.replace("Success.html");
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```